Proving that $\mathrm{Gal}(E/FL) = \mathrm{Gal}(E/F) \cap \mathrm{Gal}(E/L)$
I am trying to apply a proof related to this discussion: $\text{Gal}(FL|L) \simeq \text{Gal}(F|F\cap L)$
I have managed to prove the following:
$
\mathrm{Gal}(E/(F \cap L)) = \mathrm{Gal}(E/F) \cdot \mathrm{Gal}(E/L).
$
Here is a sketch of the proof:

Let $\sigma \in \mathrm{Gal}(E/F) \cdot \mathrm{Gal}(E/L)$. Then $\sigma = \sigma_1 \sigma_2$, where $\sigma_1 \in \mathrm{Gal}(E/F)$ and $\sigma_2 \in \mathrm{Gal}(E/L)$.
For any $x \in F \cap L$, we have $\sigma_1(x) = x$ (since $\sigma_1$ fixes $F$) and $\sigma_2(x) = x$ (since $\sigma_2$ fixes $L$). Hence, $\sigma(x) = \sigma_1(\sigma_2(x)) = x$, which implies $\sigma \in \mathrm{Gal}(E/(F \cap L))$.
This shows $\mathrm{Gal}(E/F) \cdot \mathrm{Gal}(E/L) \subseteq \mathrm{Gal}(E/(F \cap L))$. Using the Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory and some intermediate steps, I proved the reverse inclusion.

However, I am struggling to prove the second part:
$
\mathrm{Gal}(E/FL) = \mathrm{Gal}(E/F) \cap \mathrm{Gal}(E/L).
$
Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Additionally, as a beginner in Galois theory, I would love recommendations for textbooks or resources that make the subject approachable, preferably ones that would help me prepare for my exam.
Thank you in advance.

This follows immediately from the definition of the Galois group and the composite field. But it's also a duplicate question as you can find by using site search.

Could you kindly help with a link, and possible any recommendations for textbooks or resources that make Galois theory approachable?

See the linked duplicates. You are on this site for quite a while already, it is worth learning to use site search. So many treasures are out there ... Notice that there are many more threads about book recommendations for Galois theory, but I couldn't add them all as duplicate targets because there is a limit. For example this one.
